# Using the same url for incoming (imap), and outgoing (smtp) mail

Tags: centos, postfix, smtp, sendmail

I have setup a postfix daemon and I am able to send emails to an account, and I am also able to login via a mail client and get those emails.

But what I'm trying to do is use the same url, e.g: mail.mydomain.org for both incoming, and outgoing mail.

So far, when I send an email with mail.mydomain.org as my outgoing mail server, it doesn't connect.

How do you debug this to understand why it isn't working?

Comment: Is the SMTP server listening on the same IP as the postfix daemon is? I'm guessing you have one physical host for SMTP/IMAP? try `telnet mail.mydomain.org 25` to establish a connection with the SMTP server. Then try different port numbers in case of an ISP block on 25

Answer (score 1):

> So far, when I send an email with mail.mydomain.org as my outgoing mail server, it doesn't connect.
>   How do you debug this to understand why it isn't working?

Your mail server needs to listen on port 25 (SMTP) and possibly also on port 587 (Submission) on `mail.mydomain.org` for this to work. Use a port scanner such as nmap **on the external client, not on the server** to check which ports on `mail.mydomain.org` are open:

```
nmap mail.mydomain.org
```

It should show at least port 25 for SMTP as opened, and also the POP3/IMAP ports so you can retrieve mails with your mail client.

On the server itself, you can use netstat to show which program is listening on which port:

```
netstat -lntp
```

Beware though that listening alone may not be enough. You also need to make sure:

- both foreign address and local address for the SMTP port in netstat show `0.0.0.0`, so that external clients may really connect. If you mail server is e.g. listening only on 127.0.0.1, then only programs running on the same server may connect.
- if the server has a firewall: make sure that the firewall allows external connections to the SMTP port. You can disable the firewall for testing purposes to rule out a firewall misconfiguration.
- if the server is behind a NAT router: make sure that you have configured the router to forward port 25 to the server.

Comment: What a superb answer. Well I got nmap and ran the command and neither 25 or 587 are available. I modified /etc/postfix/main.cf and changed inet_interfaces from 'localhost' to 'all'. Restarted. I ran the netstat command you gave on the server, and it shows that 'sendmail' is using port 25: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1243/sendmail . But i ran nmap again and nothing is listening on 25.

Comment: Have you ruled out the firewall? Is the server directly connected to the Internet, or behind a NAT router that needs additional port forwardings? You could also try "telnet mail.mydomain.org 25" or "nc mail.mydomain.org 25" - maybe nmap isn't showing the port for some reason, but you could still connect?

Comment: I still couldn't connect. The server is a vps - I will log a support ticket and see if they know what the situation is

Comment: Run a ping from the VPS to a client machine you control, see what the source address is via `tcpdump -n -i any icmp` and vice-versa. Make sure you can trade icmp packets back and forth first, then work up to tcp packets and specific ports.